# Data type added as string when creating variable ...array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)

Tags: python

When I change my array data type, using `.astype()` or by adding to `np.array(list,dtype=)`, I get an array which has a string attached. Why is this happening? (example below)

```
In [1]: A=[1,2,3]

In [2]: A=np.array(A,np.float32)

In [3]: A.dtype
Out[3]: dtype('float32')

In [4]: A
Out[4]: array([1., 2., 3.], dtype=float32)

In [5]: AA=[3,4,5]

In [6]: AA=np.array(AA)

In [7]: AA
Out[7]: array([3, 4, 5])

In [8]: AA.dtype
Out[8]: dtype('int32')

In [9]: AA.astype(np.float32())
Out[9]: array([3., 4., 5.], dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a string: `dtype('float32')`. It's just one way of representing the dtype for a 32bits float.

If you had strings in your array, you would see:

```
dtype('S1')
```

or:

```
dtype('object')
```

Answer (score 1):

You're converting your types correctly and the `, dtype=float32` attached to your array is not an attached string but just the data type that's displayed in the representation of a Numpy array.

If you do

```
print(AA)
```

you will only see your array without any strings following.